# loader en peticion de api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

bueno necesito agregar un loader antes de que se cargue una peticion a una API de instragram, lo estoy haciendo en react, como hago para tener un componente renderizado de un loader y una vez que tenga la respuesta de la API renderizar ese resultado, el codigo seria algo asi, tengo que cambiar algo de aca? o el componente donde renderizo esto?

```
function Instagram () {

  let FeedInstagram =`https://graph.instagram.com/me/mediafields
    =thumbnail_url,media_url,children,children_url,timestam 
   p,media_type,caption,permalink&limit= 
   10&access_token=${token}`

   const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(FeedInstagram)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => json.data)
        .then((info) => setData(info))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
     }, [FeedInstagram]);

     return(
      <div>
        {data?.map((el)=>{
        return (
        <React.Fragment key={el.id}>
          { (el.media_type === 'IMAGE' ||  el.media_type === 'CAROUSEL_ALBUM') && <Card key= 
    {el.id} titulo={el.caption} img={el.media_url} fecha={el.timestamp} /> }
  
          { el.media_type === 'VIDEO' && <Video key={el.id} titulo={el.caption} video= 
    {el.media_url} fecha={el.timestamp} /> } 
        </React.Fragment>);
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solución

La forma más simple es chequear el valor de `data` y en base a eso renderizar un loader o la respuesta de la API.

Esto sería, si `data` es `null` todavía sigo esperando la respuesta de la api, si data no es `null` significa que ya me respondió (En realidad todavía nos falta chequear si hubo un error en la respuesta).

```javascript
function Instagram () {

  let FeedInstagram =`https://graph.instagram.com/me/mediafields
    =thumbnail_url,media_url,children,children_url,timestam 
   p,media_type,caption,permalink&limit= 
   10&access_token=${token}`

   const [data, setData] = useState(null); // Inicializo data como null

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(FeedInstagram) // Mientras la API no responda, data va a seguir siendo null
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => json.data)
        .then((info) => setData(info)) // Cuando responda, data dejará de ser null (Recuerda chequear si hay errores)
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
     }, [FeedInstagram]);

     return(
      <div>
        {!data && (<div> Loading </div>)}

        {data?.map((el)=>{
        return (
        <React.Fragment key={el.id}>
          { (el.media_type === 'IMAGE' ||  el.media_type === 'CAROUSEL_ALBUM') && <Card key= 
    {el.id} titulo={el.caption} img={el.media_url} fecha={el.timestamp} /> }
  
          { el.media_type === 'VIDEO' && <Video key={el.id} titulo={el.caption} video= 
    {el.media_url} fecha={el.timestamp} /> } 
        </React.Fragment>);
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

### Chequeando error de API

Para chequear un error puede ser usando un estado para el error.

Si la API nos responde con un error lo seteamos y lo mostramos.

Esto es porque tenemos 3 estados:

- Cargando
- Respuesta exitosa
- Error

```javascript
function Instagram () {

  let FeedInstagram =`https://graph.instagram.com/me/mediafields
    =thumbnail_url,media_url,children,children_url,timestam 
   p,media_type,caption,permalink&limit= 
   10&access_token=${token}`

   const [data, setData] = useState(null); // Inicializo data como null
   const [error, setError] = useState(null); // Inicializo error como null

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(FeedInstagram) // Mientras la API no responda, data va a seguir siendo null
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => json.data)
        .then((info) => setData(info)) // Cuando responda, data dejará de ser null (Recuerda chequear si hay errores)
        .catch((err) => {
            setError(err.message); // Si hay un error, lo guardo en error
            console.log(err)
        })
     }, [FeedInstagram]);

     return(
      <div>
        {!data && (<div> Loading </div>)}
        {error && (<div> {error} </div>)}

        {data?.map((el)=>{
        return (
        <React.Fragment key={el.id}>
          { (el.media_type === 'IMAGE' ||  el.media_type === 'CAROUSEL_ALBUM') && <Card key= 
    {el.id} titulo={el.caption} img={el.media_url} fecha={el.timestamp} /> }
  
          { el.media_type === 'VIDEO' && <Video key={el.id} titulo={el.caption} video= 
    {el.media_url} fecha={el.timestamp} /> } 
        </React.Fragment>);
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
```